SQLAlchemy ORM: understanding attribute type conversion/enforcement
Please consider the following code and console output. The ORM class TestTable has the column (or attribute) timestamp mapped to a type datetime.
When I SELECT from database, the returned object (see obj_from_db variable) type() of this attribute is <class 'datetime.datetime'> (as I intended in the TestTable class declaration).
But when I instantiate it directly (see obj_created variable), using a string (common ISO format for date/time), the type does not have converted (or enforced) to be datetime. Despite this non-conversion, the insertion into the database works correctly.
I would like to know:

What does SQLAlchemy do to fill this attribute with the correct type (<class 'datetime.datetime'>) when SELECTing from DB? I think it is calling datetime.fromisoformat(<text from sql result>) somewhere...

How can I enforce the same behavior when manually (directly) creating an ORM object? In other words, how can I instruct SQLAlchemy to always store the timestamp as <class 'datetime.datetime'> (even when provided as str)?


#!/usr/bin/python3

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from datetime import datetime

# declarative base class
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# declare a object to be mapped to a table in database
class TestTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test_table"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    timestamp: Mapped[datetime]
    version: Mapped[int]

# create a database engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://@/my_db', echo=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    # create object 'directly'
    obj_created = TestTable(name='new one', timestamp='2024-12-27 13:49:56', version=7)

    # put it on session
    session.add(obj_created)

    # print the type of the obj_created timestamp attribute
    print('type(obj_created.timestamp) (object created): ', type(obj_created.timestamp))

    # commit objects in this session to the database
    session.commit()

    # select one item from database (any)
    obj_from_db = session.scalars(select(TestTable)).first()

    if obj_from_db is not None:
        # print the type of the obj_from_db timestamp attribute
        print('type(obj_from_db.timestamp) (object from DB): ', type(obj_from_db.timestamp))


Console output:
type(obj_created.timestamp) (object created):  <class 'str'>
type(obj_from_db.timestamp) (object from DB):  <class 'datetime.datetime'>

